# Вопросительные знаки при записи в mySQL (SQL). Java

Tags: java, mysql

Пытаюсь изучить Java + MySQL, у меня при записи в базу, если указывать русские символы, записывается так ?????

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Куда копать? В IntrlliJ внизу справа написано utf-8

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В mySql настроена кодировка такая:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

сам код

```
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://*********.com:3306/*****?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8";
        String user = "*****";
        String pass = "****";
    ...
                Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
                Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
                System.out.print("Введите имя плательщика: ");
                String name = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine().trim();
                System.out.print("Оплата: ");
                double money = new Scanner(System.in).nextDouble();
                statement.execute("INSERT INTO info (`name`, `money`) VALUES ('" + name + "', '" + money + "')");
                statement.close();
                connection.close();
```

Comment: Код покажите, как мы узнаем что вы пишите

Comment: Спасибо за замечание, показал код

Comment: Вы запускаете код в консоли. А консоль в какой кодировке работает? С вероятностью 146% не utf-8

Comment: @ArchDemon Запускаю в IntelliJ, там внизу справа написано utf-8, в cmd указал команду C:\Users\nikol>chcp
Active code page: 65001

Comment: В idea показана кодировка файла кода, а не консоли. Попробуйте вставить данные напрямую из кода. Если вопросительных знаков не будет, то проблема, очевидно, в консоли.

Comment: Вставил данные напрямую из кода, все равно добавляется как ??????

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13063372/hibernate-mysql-how-to-set-the-encoding-utf-8-for-database-and-tables попробуйте что-то из этого